# Count ammount of <li> are into a div and post somewhere, js

Tags: javascript, count

-------- EDIT ------------

This workz!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.ammount-reclame').text($("#count-reclame li").length)
       $('.ammount-portret').text($("#count-portret li").length)
       $('.ammount-reportage').text($("#count-reportage li").length)
     });
</script>

<ul> 
    <li>
        <div class="number">
            <div class="ammount-reclame"> </div> images
        </div>
    </li>

    <ul id="count-reclame" class="hidden">
        <li><a href="assets/images/portfolio/dummy/background_1.jpg">x</a></li>
        <li><a href="assets/images/portfolio/dummy/background_4.jpg">x</a></li>
        <li><a href="assets/images/portfolio/dummy/background_5.jpg">x</a></li>
    </ul>

    etc..

</ul>
```

------- EDIT -------

I need to output a number, I have several divs with images into them like below.
I'm not that good at javascript, maybe someone can help me out?

```
<div class="fl ammount-pizza">//pizza number here = 3//</div>
<div class="fl ammount-cheese">//cheese number here = 2//</div>
etc..

<div id="count-pizza" class="hidden">
  <li><img src="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" /></li>
</div>

<div id="count-cheese" class="hidden">
  <li><img src="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" /></li>
</div>

etc..
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#count-pizza li").length,
        show count at div.class= ammount-pizza;

      $("#count-cheese li").length,
        show count at div.class= ammount-cheese;
    etc..

    });
</script>
```

Or maybe it can be shorten a couple of lines by using the unique id name and output on that same class name? *Classnames and ID's can have other names as above.*

Comment: `li` elements without `ul`?

Comment: @Sachin who needs `ul`'s when we got pizza?

Comment: @lostsource yeah you are right *pizza along with cheese* :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ammount-pizza').text($("#count-pizza li").length)
    $('.ammount-cheese').text($("#count-cheese li").length)
});
```

also your html is invalid, the `li` element has to be inside either `ol` or `ul` elements.

Ex:

```
<ul id="count-pizza" class="hidden">
  <li><img src="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" /></li>
  <li><img src="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah yeah it is in a <ul> actually but forgot it on my example.
THX, I will give your script a try!

Comment: Why doesn't it work??? I don't see whats wrong here. I updated my post see above!

Comment: Hmm, when I paste it in a clean html file it does work, your script is oké! there must be some script conflict going on?!.

Comment: Oké the code was oké after all, the problem was when I was on n URL like site.com/#contact and I refreshed! (with Firefox) then it didn't work anymore. Weird, must be ajax I'm using?!

Thx again anyway!